# Hosting two React apps from two Buckets on one CloudFront distribution. How to deal with two static directories?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, npm, amazon-cloudfront

I have two React apps I want to serve with one CloudFront distribution. They both rely on react-router for navigation.

I have two S3 buckets configured as origins. The default (*) behaviour is set to my one bucket that hosts the landing page. I want certain other URLs (like /dashboard, /task) to use my other bucket.

This works fine setting up behaviours that pattern match those certain paths, but I'm stuck on one thing. Building a React app defaults scripts that the app needs to run to a "static" directory. I have to set a behaviour static* for one or the other and only the one that the behaviour points to works.

Is there anything I can do to work around this? From searching I haven't found any way to tell npm run-script build to build an app that uses a differently named static directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I took the following steps to fix this:

In package.json add the option "homepage": "landing"

Rebuild the react app with npm run-script build

Upload the files to the bucket but put *assets* and *static* into a *landing* directory.

Add a new behaviour on CloudFront that redirects landing/* to the landing bucket.

It seems to work fine now.

Comment: Hi, I have 2 react apps, one sitting on `/` and the other one `/app`, same domain. How did you prevent the first app from navigating on the `/app` path and leave it up to the second app? Because how does the first app know what is a client side path and which one is serverside?